# on build vuejs creates empty hashed files

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, vuejs3, webpack-5

When I build my project I get empty image files in dist folder. These are used by vuejs for caching (thats what I figured out), so when I open project in browser images dont work. This is my first javascript project and I cant find solution for this problem.
I want to disable caching, first of all it creates empty files and also it duplicates files (I already have assets folder).
For me it looks like vue.config.js isnt loading. I dont use vue-cli, I build project with npm.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "kekwxd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.16.4",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "precss": "^4.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.6",
    "vue-loader": "^16.5.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.3.6",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.1.1",
    "sass": "^1.38.2",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.51.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./src/main.js",
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    chunkFilename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: "vue-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?\S*)?$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "[name].[ext]",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webm|mp4|svg)$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "[name].[ext]",
          outputPath: "assets/",
          esModule: false,
        },
      },
      {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
              'vue-style-loader',
              {
                  loader: 'css-loader'
              },
              'postcss-loader'
          ]
      },
          {
              test: /\.scss$/,
              use: [{
                  loader: 'vue-style-loader', // inject CSS to page
              }, {
                  loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS modules
              }, {
                  loader: 'postcss-loader', // Run post css actions
                  options: {
                      postcssOptions: {
                          plugins: [require('precss'),
                              require('autoprefixer')]
                      }
                  }
              }, {
                  loader: 'sass-loader' // compiles Sass to CSS
              }]
          },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[name].css",
    }),
    new htmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
      favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.vue' ],
    alias: {
        'vue': '@vue/runtime-dom'
    }
  },
  optimization: {
    moduleIds: "hashed",
    runtimeChunk: "single",
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: "vendors",
          priority: -10,
          chunks: "all",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
};
```

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    filenameHashing: false,
    // ...
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
        config.module
            .rule("images")
            .use("url-loader")
            .loader("url-loader")
            .tap((options) => {
                options.fallback.options.name = "img/[name].[ext]"
                return options
            })
    }
    // ...
}
```

src/main.js

```
import './scss/app.scss';
import 'bootstrap';
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

global.gui = { chat: null, hud: null, notify: null, modals: [] }
const app = createApp(App).use(router).mount("#app")
export default app;

global.app = app;
```

Comment: `vue.config.js` isn't loaded because that file is only read by Vue CLI. Why don't you just use Vue CLI? Its sensible defaults will simplify the project config for you.

Comment: Because Vue CLI needs to be installed globally and that doesnt fits in my environment

Comment: You can use `npx @vue/cli` to run it without global installation.